# Out of two hazelcast instances how to make eviction event to be consumed just by one of them?

Tags: hazelcast

When using controlled eviction with added TTL like:

```
myMap.put( "1", "John", 50, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
```

On two application instances using hazelcast which belong to the same group and identify each other correctly during startup, when implementing our own `EntryExpiredListener`, we notice that both instances receive the same event in:

```
@Override
public void entryExpired(EntryEvent<String, SomeObject> event) {
       ...
}
```

We would expect only one hazelcast instance to process the event, is this correct behavior? How can we configure just one instance to consume such event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, the IMap has method `addLocalEntryListener` , registering listener such way will make events to come just to the instance which owns the entries.

```
Also note that entries can migrate to
other nodes for load balancing and/or membership change.
```